# What is unclear about question 14741?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

The following question was "on hold"  for being unclear.

https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14741/how-could-the-prophet-pbuh-not-assign-a-successor-after-his-death-sunni-brot

In fact this question is asking for a comparison between the situations of the prophet and Abu Bakr which led to different decision in choosing a successor.

- Although the users believed that this was not unclear (please read the comments), I tried to clarify my question. After a while, the question was "Closed".
- It is now deleted for the same reason (because a moderator believes that it is unclear even after edition)

Now, I would like to ask you to help me with determining the vague and unclear parts of the question.

- **Update:** Most of the mentioned comments showing the question is clear, are deleted by a moderator!!!

Comment: Oh,@Mohammad Hossein, you are right, Since to be honest, I didn’t find any specific unclear point in your question. Vice versa I believe that it is seriously a fundamental and significant question which its rational response could has a profitable effect in showing the right way(for Muslims).

Comment: I explained exactly why I closed it in my own comment when I closed it. What of that explanation did you not understand?

Comment: @goldPseudo ...and I asked you for more explanation which you didn't answer, and edited my question as an attempt to clarify my question.

Answer (score 2):

I would say the question is still unclear because:

- the title is *"How Could the prophet (PBUH) not assign a successor after his death? (Sunni brother's View)"* and it's out of sync with the main body of the question
- the body of the question is asking as to compare facts which AFAIK is not a good fit for an SE site. That makes the question broad. (*"Please compare the situations of the Prophet and Abu Bakr which led to different decision for choosing successor, having the above in mind."*)

goldPseudo's comment

> This really isn't a clear question; are you asking for why the prophet didn't assign a successor, or are you asking for why Abu Bakr did? They are very different questions.

in that respect was crystal clear and since that problem was not addressed in all the ensuing edits a deletion wasn't out of place.

Comment: You are late. the post is unfortunately deleted.