# Why is question 14741 deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

[What is unclear about question 14741?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1211/what-is-unclear-about-question-14741) had no benefit for me to know the unclear points of [the question,](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/14741/how-could-the-prophet-pbuh-not-assign-a-successor-after-his-death-sunni-brot) (although I believed it was  clear, I raised that for possible clarifications).
Surprisingly, now I see that it's deleted!!! And no reason is mentioned for deletion.

I want to know why it is deleted?

Answer (score 2):

I occasionally go through closed questions on the site and delete those that have not made sufficient effort to improve.  Leaving closed questions on the site just adds noise, which is antithesis to the Stack Exchange model.

In this case, your question was closed for being unclear.  Even after your edits, it is still ambiguous:

- If you were you asking why the Prophet didn't assign a successor, it would be a fine question.
- If you were asking why Abu Bakr chose to assign his own successor, that would also be a fine question.

The leading question at the end, on the other hand, suggested that you were not actually interested in learning the answers to *either* of those questions.  Rhetorical questions may be fine for discussion, but they are *definitely* not what the Stack Exchange model is geared toward.

The whole thing just came off as exactly the sort of rhetorical polemic that's likely to inflame [the same sorts of sectarianism](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/275/22) that we've been fighting on this site since the beginning.  In other words, if it was left open, I don't see that anything constructive would have come from it.

And if nothing constructive would have come from it, there's no reason for it to stay on the site.

Comment: The problem is that, the question is exactly asking both of them at the same time, because **I Wanted the users to compare the situation of prophet and Abu Bakr** by this post. Consequently, there is no reason to regard any parts of this post as being rhetorical. On the other hand, the possible answers to this question will add to knowledge of the readers on such an important point of Islamic history and hence deserves to be answered by the users.